# Compiler says variable was not declared, but it is declared on the previous line

Tags: c++

I'm using MingW as my compiler. I have declared a variable, `strl`, but it says that it wasn't declared at the line right under it.

```
struct idstruct {
    char * path;
    lua_State **state;
};

idstruct ids[] = {};
int nids = 0;

static char* getPath(lua_State **state) {
  std::cout << state;
  for (int on = 0; on < nids; on++)
    idstruct strl = ids[on];
    if (strl.state == state) {
      return strl.path;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Zero-length arrays are illegal. It's also illegal indexing a zero-length array with any index if it happens to compile in the first place.

Comment: At this stage of your career, it is more likely that the compiler is right than you are.  That even happens after you've been programming a decade or two or three, [sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020208/why-is-gcc-4-8-2-complaining-about-addition-under-strict-overflow), though generally you feel that the compiler is wrong less frequently after a few years.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a curly brace at the start of your for loop's body. By the time you reach the following `if` statement, `strl` has gone out of scope.

Answer (score 4):

You've left off a brace on your for loop, so it's just a one-liner, despite your indentation. Thus the variable is not in scope in the `if` statement below it.

Try this:

```
  for (int on = 0; on < nids; on++) {  // add a brace here
    idstruct strl = ids[on];
    if (strl.state == state) {
      return strl.path;
    }
  }  // and here
```